# expect script for ping test

Tags: bash, shell, expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
    
    set IPaddress [lindex $argv 0]
    set fildes [open "ip.txt" r]
    set output [open "out.txt"]
    
while {[gets $fildes ip ] != -1} {
    
    set timeout 5
    spawn ping -c 3 $ip
    expect  {
        " 0%"   {puts "$ip Is Up"}
        " 100%" {puts "$ip Is Down"}
        }
}
```

I'm making a script to test ping and put the output to a file.
I want to write the puts "$ip Is Up" and $ip Is Down to the file `out.txt`.
Then I want to count how many IPs are up and how many are down.
Like:

```
30 Ips Is up
20 Ips Is down
```

I want the count in `out.txt` also.

Comment: What if you get a percentage in between 0 and 100?

Comment: `puts $output "$ip is Up"`?

Comment: this is why i put ping -c 3 to send 3 icmp packets. usually sending 3 icmp packets will be 0 if device up

Comment: sorry but your answer didnt work it's show's this "puts $output "$ip Is Up""
    invoked from within

Comment: Sometimes the first ping fails because it takes time to fill the ARP cache, but the other two succeed, so you get 33% loss.

Answer (score 0):

its work now i just need to add "w" this is my code update:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

    set IPaddress [lindex $argv 0]
    set fildes [open "ip.txt" r]
    set output [open "out.txt" w]

while {[gets $fildes ip ] != -1} {

    set timeout 5
    spawn ping -c 3 $ip
    expect  {
        " 0%"   {puts $output "$ip Is Up"}
        " 100%" {puts $output "$ip Is Down"}
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add w"?

Comment: To get the counts you want, you can simply increment a variable in each of the expect clauses.